# Enumerate all NICs with IP and MAC addresses in powershell

Tags: powershell

How can I list all NICs with name, MAC and IP address in PowerShell?

I know that I can combine Get-NetIPAddress and  Get-NetAdapter but is there a simple way to do it because it seems to be one of the most common things in network management.

I've also found that Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed, but I don't understand why `Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | select InterfaceAlias,NetAdapter.LinkLayerAddress,IPv4Address` returns empty MAC addresses.

Comment: You have to calculate sub properties when using them in a select statement, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WMI class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration contains this information:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computer localhost | Select Description, MACAddress, IPAddress
```

And more:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computer localhost | Select *
```

Using `NetIPConfiguration -Detailed`, you have to calculate the sub property LinkLayerAddress when using it in a select statement:

```
NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | 
    select InterfaceAlias, 
           IPv4Address, {$_.NetAdapter.LinkLayerAddress}
```

The above works, but we can give the calculated property a name, like this:

```
NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | 
select InterfaceAlias, 
       IPv4Address,
       @{
            name = 'MacAddress'
            expr = {$_.NetAdapter.LinkLayerAddress}
        }
```

Finally, as a one-liner:

```
NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | select InterfaceAlias, IPv4Address, @{name = 'MacAddress'; expr = {$_.NetAdapter.LinkLayerAddress}}
```

Comment: Thanks, nimizen! Just help me to understand it better, I thought calculated properties are used to combine and transform existing ones, why can't I access sub property directly? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: I guess calculated property isn't really the correct terminology; what we're doing is expanding a property, in this case, allowing a script property to return its result, I logically think of this as an enumeration/calculation. We can see that `NetIPConfiguration -Detailed` is actually returning properties of multiple cmdlets including `NetAdapter`.  Running `NetAdapter | Get-Member` shows that the NetAdapter cmdlet has an alias property of LinkLayerAddress which is an AliasProperty for MacAddress, MacAddress is a ScriptProperty.

Comment: Running `NetAdapter| Get-Member MacAddress | select -ExpandProperty Definition` allows us to see that a script is run to return that property.  We could run `NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | select -ExpandProperty NetAdapter | select InterfaceAlias, LinkLayerAddress, IPv4Address` but then we would change the pipeline and lose access to the IPv4 Address property of NetIPConfiguration.
Wrapping `$_.NetAdapter.LinkLayerAddress` in an expression allows it to be expanded without changing the pipeline.

Comment: What do you mean by "expanded without changing the pipeline"?

Comment: Using the example in my previous comment, `NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | ` at this point the NetIPConfiguration is passed down the pipe. `NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | select -ExpandProperty NetAdapter | ` at this point we've changed the object being passed down the pipe to a NetAdapter object that doesn't contain the IPv4Address property, therefore, we can no longer select it.  By expanding the NetAdapter.LinkLayerAddress property of the NetIPConfiguration object in an expression, as per my answer, the only object passed down the pipe is NetIPCoinfiguration so all properties are available.